# c# dotnetbar two listboxadv sync scroll not working

Tags: c#, scroll, dotnetbar

i have two ListBoxAdv1 and ListBoxAdv2  and i want sync them scroll
i use this code and just scroll up or down but didn't update showing items in other ListBoxAdv
what should i do?
please help

i try this:

```
 private void listBoxAdv1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
 {
        listBoxAdv2.VScrollBar.Value = listBoxAdv1.VScrollBar.Value;     
 }
 private void listBoxAdv2_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
 {
       listBoxAdv1.VScrollBar.Value = listBoxAdv2.VScrollBar.Value;
 }
```

and this:

```
private void listBoxAdv1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
       listBoxAdv2.Focus();
       ScrollEventArgs scrollEventArgs = new ScrollEventArgs(ScrollEventType.SmallIncrement, e.OldValue, e.NewValue, ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll);
       listBoxAdv2_Scroll(listBoxAdv2, scrollEventArgs);
}
private void listBoxAdv2_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score -1):

thanks for many responses!
i find solution:

```
 bool Scrolling = true;
        private void listBoxAdv1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Scrolling == true)
            {
                Scrolling = false;
                listBoxAdv2.BeginUpdate();
                listBoxAdv2.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(listBoxAdv1.AutoScrollPosition.X, listBoxAdv1.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
                listBoxAdv2_Scroll(sender, e);
                listBoxAdv2.EndUpdate();
                Scrolling = true;
            }
        }

        private void listBoxAdv2_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Scrolling == true)
            {
                Scrolling = false;
                listBoxAdv1.BeginUpdate();
                listBoxAdv1.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(listBoxAdv2.AutoScrollPosition.X, listBoxAdv2.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
                listBoxAdv1_Scroll(sender, e);
                listBoxAdv1.EndUpdate();
                Scrolling = true;
            }
        }
```